# Insufficent space for downloading APP from Play store

Tags: applications, internal-storage

I am using a Micromax Canvas HD, which has an internal memory of 2Gb and the **free memory** is 1.3 Gb

I also have an 8Gb memory card on which the free memory is about 3.2 Gb and I'm am still getting the error: `no sufficient Storage for downloading`.

Comment: Does your phone support moving applications to SD card? and what is the size of the application you're downloading?

Comment: as mani says, what is the size of the application you are downloading?

Comment: "Downloading" always goes to internal storage, never to any SDCard – regardless of where the app might end up. And that's what the "insufficient storage" error points to always, see [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/internal-storage/info).